# Parent Child User accounts in .NET

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, security, membership-provider

I am working on a system where I have implemented the membership provider to handle accounts.

What I require is a way of having various users say "Admins" create child accounts for their staff.  I would guess this is some sort of hierarchy design.

Previously I have done this where the authentication/security of the application has been completely custom so no membership provider involved.

The number of users will be in the hundreds of thousands and I wanted to use the provider because it saves time on developing a custom solution.

Should I use the provider or develop a custom solution to handle this stype of parent/child user data, or extend the provider add extra field say "Creator" and use the ID of whoever created the user in the first place so I can get a list of users whenever the admin logs in using his ID.

Any help appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: I usually leave all the Membership tables alone and add a new table called UserData.

Comment: Why was this down voted as I have not seen the question before on SO?

Comment: So what would you put in the UserData table? Would it be the hierachy data of the Users eg. ParentID, ChildID?

Comment: `UserId`, `ParentId` should suffice. You can set `ParentId` to `null` for admins.

Comment: So take the UserID from the standard membership provider and store that in the UserData table and use that table for any lookups correct?

Comment: @AliK: There are multiple reasons that a question might be down-voted or voted to be closed, and a duplicate is just one of those reasons. More importantly, the question must be something that gives enough information so that it can be accurately answered. In this case, the answer is opinion based: all three options you give will get you what you want. However, you ask what is the "best" way to do  something. This might depend on more than just code: what is the political situation of the project you're working on.

Comment: Not sure why this has been put on hold as it is pretty clear and marked as 'answered'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd try to avoid messing with the membership tables. Create a separate `UserData` table in the database. This should have the same `UserId` primary key as the membership users table, and then contain other custom information. In particular, a `ParentId` column. For child users, this can refer to the appropriate administrator, and for administrators it can be set to `null`.

In ASP.NET when a user logs in, let the membership system authenticate them and then query the `UserData` table to find out additional information (in this case, who their parent user is).

Comment: Cheers I thought it would be something like that I guess using the MVC I can create a model to have my membership and custom objects work together as I have the membership provider in a complete seperate project and custom objects somewhere else.